# Use HABTM using transactions in empty Database CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm trying to store my data in an empty database using Transactions. Now this doesn't work for me. This is my ERD: https://www.dropbox.com/s/pfakd7xplsvr7cc/db_erd.PNG

Notice that at first all three tables are empty. And I send the following array to the database:

```
array(
    'Product' => array(
        'slug' => 'c24b626d6701d3b07e30b233b989ff8811',
        'product_name' => 'DAHLIA 5A',
        'price_new' => '159.00',
        'affiliate_url' => 'http://example.com/feed.xml',
        'product_id_supplier' => 'c24b626d670133d3b07e30b2b989ff8811',
        'supplier_id' => 'some_supplier',
        'feedimport_id' => (int) 1
    ),
    'Image' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'image' => 'product_image.JPG'
        )
    ),
    'Term' => array(
        'Term' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                'name' => 'Tommy Hilfiger'
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Using $this->getDataSource(); . But it only fills the images and products table. If I look at the log file, it appears it tries to select from the products_terms table, after inserting the products and images table, and ofcourse it receives nothing back. And there it stops.... It doesn't try to insert in the terms table either.

Now if I look at tutorials like these: http://www.pabloleanomartinet.com/cakephp-2-x-saving-and-validating-a-habtm-relation-example/
It looks like I don't do anything wrong... But if I look closely it looks like the TAGS table in the tutorial is filled already.... So probably that's the problem? But I don't know how to get a Term ID first, before inserting the product and linking them together, using transactions....

Anyone who does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. It seems like the Terms table needs to be filled, else cakePHP doesn't know which term to connect to.

So the proper solution is to first check or the Term exists, else insert the Term in the Terms table, and then insert the products using HABTM (using the ID of the Term in the insert array), so the products_terms table will be filled also.